# NullPointerException on an action declaration in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I have a button and I want it to run a method when it is clicked, here is the code for that button...

```
             playAgainButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        action(e);
                    }

public void action(ActionEvent e) {

                        Main.playerTurn = true;
                        Main.computerWon = false;
                        Main.playerWon = false;

                        button1.setText("");
                        button2.setText("");
                        button3.setText("");
                        button4.setText("");
                        button5.setText("");
                        button6.setText("");
                        button7.setText("");
                        button8.setText("");
                        button9.setText("");
                    }
                    });
```

but i get a NullPointer error here is that as well...

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at tictactoe.tictactoe.initComponents(tictactoe.java:281)
    at tictactoe.tictactoe.<init>(tictactoe.java:13)
    at tictactoe.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:30)
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Comment: i will post that into the original now

Answer (score 5):

`playAgainButton` could be `null`! Check if it is `null` or not:

```
System.out.print("Is playAgainButton null? " + (playAgainButton == null));
```

Comment: how can i do this if i cannot run the program?

Comment: @CodeLover Place the printing statement just before `playAgainButton.addActionListener(`.

Comment: @ Eng.Fouad it came out true... What should i do?

Comment: @CodeLover: You need to learn about what NPE means in general -- that you're trying to use a null variable, and what you need to do about in general -- you need to initialize all variables before using them.